# BufferedReader reads just one line in an multiple line file

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I tried to archive that a multiline file will be read from an `BufferedReader`. But this `BufferedReader` reads just one line and exiting his `while()`. Before he can read this, another method of the same class should've been written in this file (not at the same time), mostly more than one line. The file contains different types of variables, such as `int[]`, `int`, `double[]`, `String`. At the end of one object, or nearly just the data that I've to collect that I can re-calculate the whole object, the `ObjectOutputStream` pastes `"\n"`. I just write parsed Strings in this file.

In my case, it's a workaround for the `ObjectInputStream`, cause this stream throws an `EOFException` every time. For those who don't know the `EOFException`: it will be thrown if the reader reaches end of file while reading.

I tried to:

- set the input string for the BufferedReader to another line
- `.close()` the Reader and make it `new`
- set `while(1)`
- write other Datatypes, such as the whole Object
  but all without any changes. The `BufferedReader` reads just one line and the `ObjectInputStream` throws `EOFException`.

```java
LinkedList<SomeAnotherSelfMadeClass> list;
File file = new File(fullPath)    // fullPath = absolute path to the file
FileInputStream fileInputStream;
BufferedReader bufferedReader;

public static LinkedList<SomeAnotherSelfMadeClass> readFile()
{
    list = new LinkedList<SomeAnotherSelfMadeClass>();
    fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file); // could be FileReader
    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileInputStream);
    String helper, anotherHelper;

    while ((helper = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
    {
        while ((anotherHelper = scanner.hasNext()) != null)
        // here's some code with scanner-things, it shouldn't be necessary to
        // know. In fact the scanner help to gather the data from the file and
        // create an object of SomeAnotherSelfMadeCLass and put it into the list
    }

    bufferedReader.close();
    fileInputStream.close();

    return list;
}
```

What can I do that I can read all lines of the file and re-calcuate my objects that are pasted in there?

I don't know either; it is better to work with the `ObjectInputStream` or with the `BufferedReader`? What can I do that the `ObjectInputStream` don't throws the `EOFException` (every time I worked with the `ObjectInputStream` I wrote the whole Object via `ObjectOutputStream`)?

P.S.: I don't have internet atm at home, so it could take a while that I'm able to answer.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have another process (or thread) that is writing data to the file that this code is reading. Is that correct? If so, how are you ensuring that the other process is **always** at least one record ahead of this one? If this process attempts to read a record before the other process has written its record, then this one will get an EOF. If this is what you are doing you might want to search "tailing a file in java"

Comment: No. It pastes earlier. You can say: before I read, all of the necessary Objects are written in this file. After it has finished, i'm able to read.

Comment: So the other process has completed and the file is fully written? How many records are in it? Also, what is the definition of `scanner`?

Comment: try this : while ((anotherHelper = scanner.nextLine()) != null)

Comment: @Gmc           It will be controlled from another class. This class write X (mostly more than one) line into this file. After finishing it sends a String to an self builded "console". Than I exit my program and starts anew - the Reader reads just one line. The ```Scanner scanner;``` gets ```scanner = new Scanner(helper);``` before the second ```while()```.

Comment: @MangduYogii   Sorry, my fault - I use ```scanner.hasNext()```. I will correct it. But this is one thing that I wll try today.

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this structure of code..**

```
BufferedReader objReader = null;
public static LinkedList<SomeAnotherSelfMadeClass> readFile()
  {
        list = new LinkedList<SomeAnotherSelfMadeClass>();
      try {

       objReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fullPath));

       while ((helper= objReader.readLine()) != null) {
                  ...........
             System.out.println(helper);//just for checking

              while ((anotherHelper = scanner.hasNextLine()) != null){
                .....
                ....
                }
       }

      } catch (IOException e) {

       e.printStackTrace();

      } finally {

       try {
        if (objReader != null)
         objReader.close();
       } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
       }
      }
```

Comment: Tried that, but it didn't helped. In fact it had the same result as I had before. But I managed to get the second output, please consider my answer to my post.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little idiot, you have to know.

The second `while()` had the condition `(anotherHelper = scanner.next()) != null`, not that what I stated before.

But I managed to get another outputs, even I tried this before (it seems that I'd misstyped at any point);

I set the first `while()` to `true`, test `helper` to break out of the `while()` and deleted the second while:

```java
    while(true)
    {
        helper = bufferedReader.readLine();

        if (helper.equals(null))
            break;

        // making things with the scanner
    }
```

It seems that the compiler had a problem with this double-while. And optimized it wrong; I think he made

```java
while (((helper = bufferedReader.readLine() != null) && (helper = scanner.nextLine()) != null)
```

out of this peace of code. That would explain why it only run once and returns `true` if I test it with `System.out.println(scanner.hasNext();` and `System.out.println(scanner.hasNextLine();` BEFORE the second while, but in it he returns not even `false`.